# Create Tabular Yes/No table for extracted words in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have list of documents and a list of keywords and I need a table in the end telling which keywords exist in which document.

My Code so far:

```
d={}
for path in pathlist:
    # because path is object not string
    path_in_str = str(path)
    file_name=ntpath.basename(path_in_str)

    pdf_file = open(path_in_str, 'rb')
    text =""
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    c = read_pdf.numPages
    for i in range(c):
        page = read_pdf.getPage(i)
        text+=(page.extractText())
        matches = re.findall(regex3, text, re.IGNORECASE)
        d["string{0}".format(file_name)] = [x[1] for x in matches]
```

So, a dict "d" has key as "Document name" and values as "Fruit names". Sample is given below:

[image]

Please note: A key can have multiple values. Till here all is working fine and correct.

I need my final output something like this:

[image: Expected Output]

Can someone please let me know how to convert the dict. to the above output.

**To be more clear**: I don't need dict to df conversion, whereas I need the values to be converted as a "Yes/No" table

Comment: Are you asking how to output your dictionary as a nice table?

Comment: Yes!! But not direct dict to df conversion. Instead whatever fruit names are there in the dict values, should be "Y" and rest as "N"

Comment: Please add a sample for the dictionary `d` :)

Comment: Have you tried constructing a dictionary with fruitnames as keys and a list of `y`'s or`n`'s for the values - the list item position relates to the document id?  Then you could use it directly to construct the DataFrame, using `Document`x as an index.

Comment: @AllaTarighati: Done

Comment: @wwii: Not sure of that approach!! As I have 1000's of documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start from here, where you created the dataframe pd_df:

```
print(pd_df)
```

Output:

```
                0       1       2
Document1   apple  banana  orange
Document2    None  orange  banana
Document3  banana   apple    None
Document4   apple    None    None
```

Now try this to create fruit_names columns (it does not matter how many columns you have in `pd_df`):

```
for fruit_name in ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']:
    pd_df.loc[:, fruit_name] = pd_df.apply(lambda x: 'y' if fruit_name in x.values.tolist() else 'n', axis=1)
print(df[['apple', 'orange', 'banana']])
```

Output:

```
          apple orange banana
Document1     y      y      y
Document2     n      y      y
Document3     y      n      y
Document4     y      n      n
```

Comment: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: check now @Rahul Agarwal

Comment: Working fine :). Can the same answer accommodate for ignoring case and plurals. So, it matches "y" for Apple, apple or Apples

Comment: Yes, just modify `lambda` statement or generaly what is inside `if` statement :)

Comment: Thanks, I have handled the ignore case part in the df creation.

Answer (score 1):

Create the dictionary the way you want it before using it as an input to the DataFrame.

I don't have your documents so I made my own:

```
import pandas as pd
import collections, re

d1 = 'apple banana cutie'
d2 = 'foo bar'
d3 = 'kiwi plum cherry'
d4 = 'orange fig tomato'
docs = [d1, d2, d3, d4]
```

For each document determine if it has interesting fruits, collect that information in a dictionary with the fruits as keys - (each key:value pair will be a column in the DataFrame).  Collect the document names in a separate container and use it as an index for the DataFrame. The position of the items in the dictionary values corresponds to the position of the items in the document names collection.

```
fruits_i_care_about = ['apple', 'kiwi', 'banana', 'plum']
pattern = '|'.join(fruits_i_care_about)
fruit_regex = re.compile(pattern)

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

doc_names = []
for n, doc in enumerate(docs):
    doc_names.append('d{}'.format(n))
    fruits_in_doc = set(fruit_regex.findall(doc))
    print(fruits_in_doc)
    for fruit in fruits_i_care_about:
        d[fruit].append('y' if fruit in fruits_in_doc else 'n')

df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=doc_names)
```

`doc` in my solution is a single string, if you only read one page at a time then it would be analogous to a page.  If possible, you might consider reading an entire pdf so you only have to perform one regex search per document.

---

The dictionary looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'apple': ['y', 'n', 'n', 'n'],
             'banana': ['y', 'n', 'n', 'n'],
             'kiwi': ['n', 'n', 'y', 'n'],
             'plum': ['n', 'n', 'y', 'n']})
```

The resultant DataFrame:

```
   apple kiwi banana plum
d0     y    n      y    n
d1     n    n      n    n
d2     n    y      n    y
d3     n    n      n    n
```

Comment: My docs are pdf and every pdf have lot of pages. So ,in your solution for me "docs" will look like a list where every element is of minimum 1000 words and the length of the list will be more than 1000 as I have 1000's of document. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Also, for fruit in fruits_i_care_about:
            d[fruit].append('y' if fruit in doc else 'n') ... my extraction is such a way that I need to use a regex and findall commands and then taking 1st element of every match as written in my code. Can you suggest making a "y"/"N" df/dict while using regex and matches?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple task in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

Comment: Actually this will only convert dict to df with dict values as cell values. Whereas I require the table like the snapshot attached in the question.

Comment: Isn't it possible to start from what @Josh Friedlander says, then `pivot` the resulting dataframe to get desired result?

Comment: @AllaTarighati: Actually  I have already done the dict to df conversion part, with the same code Josh posted. I didn't posted that in my original question as I was not sure this is the correct path to reach the output I want. I am basically stuck after this. How to get "Y"/"N" part. Also, I can have columns for which there is no matching text for any documents.

Comment: Could you use a list comprehension to change the lists in your dict-values? I.e. get a list of all fruit (columns), then `['y' if x in fruit else 'n' for x in matches ]`

Comment: Not working...as I am not getting "N" for the blank values in my dict(d) list